# Parse nested JSON w/jQuery - WP Rest API

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the WordPress JSON rest api to retrieve recent posts. So far, I can access the JSON object but I can't access the nested nodes. I can get the title and link, but I need to reformat the date and show the thumbnail. Here is my call to get the json:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'https://foo.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=1',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
            var $recent_posts = $('#posts');
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $('<div class="l-five l-p1 l-nmr">')
                .append('<div class="l-four"><img src="'+item.wp:featuredmedia[0].source_url+'" class="inline" /></div><div class="l-eight l-nmr"><a href="'+item.link+'"><h3 class="l-twelve l-mb1 f-bold f-size16 f-l-height16 t-left c-gray">'+item.title.rendered+'</h3></a><p class="l-twelve l-nmb f-reg f-size16 f-l-height16 t-left c-gray">'+item.date+'</p></div>')
            .appendTo($recent_posts);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The date is being returned as "2018-02-14T10:00:17" Can you reformat that in js?

I can't access the embed object 'thumbnail'. Here is a link to the [json pastebin](https://pastebin.com/s598VqX6)

This doesn't look right "item.wp:featuredmedia[0].source_url"

Comment: Yeah, no ':' doesn't make sense.  It's neither dot notation or array notation for accessing children of an object/array.

Comment: 'wp:featuredmedia' is a nested child under two different things; _links and _embedded.  Since the : a part of the key you will have to access it with array notation like _links["wp:featuredmedia"]

Comment: How would you access that child of an object/array? '_embedded' => 'wp:featuredmedia' => array?

Comment: Using "<img src="'+item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"]+'" />"  I get "https://foo.com/[object%20Object]" I dont know how to access that deep in a multidimensional array, researching w/no luck

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Taplar for pointing me in the right direction. The solution for my issue was `item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url` I just wasn't going down the object far enough.